# Таймер на обновление определённого div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем привет!
У меня есть html страница и мне нужно сделать так что бы **каждую 1 секунду** обновлялся только один блок на станице.

Пример моего кода

**HTML**

```
<div class="chart" id="stat"></div>
```

**JS**

```js
setInterval(function()
{
   document.getElementById('stat');
}, 10000);
```

**Задача:** обновлять блок каждую секунду, для обновления информации в нём.

Мой код не работает, подскажите как сделать так что бы информация в блоке обновлялась каждую 1 секунду.

Comment: Проблема та в чём?

Comment: Код есть, только интервал другой стоит. Или это тестовое задание?

Comment: "Проблема: мой код не работает, обновляет всю страницу." --- этот код  не может обновлять всю страницу, даже если его очень сильно об этом просить и молить бога

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Суть в том, что я хотел задать интервал на обновление на 1 конкретный блок.

Comment: и? ну вот есть блок, есть интервал........ что есть "обновлялся блок" никто, кроме вас не знает. "обновляет всю страницу" - ложь и обман

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я хочу что бы у меня обновлялась информация в этом блоке каждую секунду.

Comment: тем, что с сервака инфа прилетит (ajax) или какого рода информация обновлялась?

Comment: http://www.codething.ru/ajax.php  здесь практические примеры обновления блока по таймеру

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Там график с данными, данные я меняю через панель управления, обычной подстановкой данных. И после того как я добавил данные, мне нужно обновить страницу, что увидеть результат, а я хочу что бы он обновлялся автоматом каждую 1 секунду.

Comment: @MaximLensky Спасибо, почитаю!

Comment: @MaxWatson не самый лучший вариант дёргать сервак каждую секунду. Нужно либо кнопочку сделать "обновить данные" и обновлять по запросу, либо другой вариант - но он вам не подойдёт ибо мало скила. Так что вариант с кнопкой.  Обновить блок данными с сервака - это ajax

Comment: `а я хочу что бы он обновлялся автоматом каждую 1 секунду.` если у вас обновляются данные раз в день - такая фича только будет жрать ресурсы, если у вас все налету должно быть то может и есть в этм смысл